# Derive an equation with Faraday's law

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-derivative

I need to find what equation is satisfied by $\Psi(x,y,z,t)$ given that $\textbf{B} = \nabla \times (\textbf{z} \Psi)$ and 
$\textbf{E} = -\textbf{z} \frac{\partial \Psi}{\partial t}$ while making use of of Faraday's law $  \nabla \times \textbf{E} =  -\frac{\partial \textbf{B}}{\partial t}$ (with **z** the unity vector in the z direction). I calculated all these conditions but I can't derive a proper equation.

Comment: I think the Faraday's law should actually be $  \nabla \times \textbf{E} =-  \frac{\partial \textbf{B}}{\partial t}$

Comment: Ooh that's right, my mistake

Comment: That's right and something my calculation leads to!